# Некорректная работа слайдера - js

Tags: javascript, html, css

При перемещении по слайдеру через лкм + drag (влево, вправо) начинает тормозить слайдер: не сильно, но не заметить невозможно. Догадываюсь, что комп не вывозит нагрузку, создаваемую через event mousemove. Как спасаться?

```
const select = (s) => document.querySelector(s);

var start = 0;
var p = 0;
var move = false;


select(".showcase").addEventListener("mousedown", drag_start, false);
select(".showcase").addEventListener("mouseup", drag_stop, false);
select(".showcase").addEventListener("mousemove", drag, false); // предполагаемый корень проблемы
select(".showcase").addEventListener("mouseleave", drag_stop, false);

function drag_stop() {
    move = false;
};

function drag_start(e) {
    start = e.screenX;
    move = true;
};

function drag(e) {
    if (move) {
        p = e.screenX;
        let computedStyle = getComputedStyle(select(".showcase"));
        left = Number(computedStyle.left.slice(0, -2)) + (p - start);
        select(".showcase").style.left = left + "px";
        start = e.screenX;
    };
};
```

Пробовал добавлять задержку перед выполнением drag, но в пустую. (P.s, есть ли нормальный способ делать табуляцию при вставке кода на SO? - через tab не работает...)

Comment: Нужен воспроизводимы пример.

Comment: Alex, на панели редактирования поищите фрагмент кода, там можно вставить html/css/js и там можно делать табуляцию и также там есть автоматическое выравнивание кода(называется привести в порядок)

Comment: Михаил, буду знать. Спасибо

Answer (score 0):

На следующий день проблема решилась сама собой - зависания практически полностью пропали. Скорее всего дело, как я и догадывался, в производительности машинки, с которой смотришь сайт.